# Error handling in $q.all()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I'm using two factory calls in my controller. In both catches, I want to call separate functions to handle the errors.

what I have :

```
someFactory.functionOne().then(function (data) {
    $scope.one = data;
}).catch(functionToHandleOne());

someFactory.functionTwo().then(function (data) {
    $scope.two = data;
}).catch(functionToHandleTwo());
```

Is the any better way I can do this with $q.all() like

```
$q.all({
    one: someFactory.functionOne(),
    two: someFactory.functionTwo()
}).then (function (data) {
    $scope.one = data.one;
    $scope.two = data.two;
}).catch(
  //here I have to call functions functionToHandleOne() and functionToHandleTwo() according to error caused which function call
);
```

Comment: Catch will be executed as soon as one of the function rejects. So if you need to handle error for both the function no matter what, you can't use $q.all, otherwise just use an anonymous function and identify which function does error variable belongs to and call the appropriate function.

Answer (score 1):

var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

```
app.factory('json',function($q,$http){
  
  return function(files){
    
    var promises = files.map( function(file){
      
      var deffered  = $q.defer();
  
      $http({
        url : file,
        method: 'GET'
      }).
      success(function(data){
        deffered.resolve(data);
      }).
      error(function(error){
          deffered.reject();
      });
      
      return deffered.promise;

    })
    
    return $q.all(promises);
  }
  
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,json) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  
  json(['a.json','b.json']).then(function(datas){
    $scope.a = datas[0]
    $scope.b = datas[1]
  })

});
```

there in above full code you could find everything you needed. like

$q passed in factory and if you have multiple function there you can call all into single factory and make them really custom s your need.

you can see in controller as show in below code it will return datas.

```
  json(['a.json','b.json']).then(function(datas){
    $scope.a = datas[0]
    $scope.b = datas[1]
  })
```

"datas"  returns multiple values  of all calls so you need to use with array.

Please let me know if solve or need more research

## khajaamin

Comment: Just FYI, `$http.success` and `$http.error` are deprecated and should not be used. You should use `.then` and `.catch` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is perfectly fine. You are missing the error callback function in your 'catch' and the error argument of course.

An example:

```
$q.all({
    one: someFactory.functionOne(),
    two: someFactory.functionTwo()
}).then (function (data) {
    $scope.one = data.one;
    $scope.two = data.two;
}).catch(function(e){
 if(e.argument == 'error1')
  functionToHandleOne()();
 else
  functionToHandleTwo()();
});
```

Comment: Thats exactly my doubt is, how to call functionToHandleOne() on failure of someFactory.functionOne() and functionToHandleTwo() on failure of someFactory.functionTwo() in catch of $q.all()?

Comment: Here the problem is rejecting error as 'error1'? I can't do this because the `e` will be a dynamic value

Comment: Point is you need to fire up the correct function according to the type of error thrown. It's a good thing `e` is dynamic.